# I am trying to sort through my array producing a new array that will give me the resulting array of products over 1500

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the problem:
recieve an array
produce an array with the persons name and number of products id above 1500 and if they are below 1500 (1436 - 1600 ) you cant include them.

```
     customers = [ { name :" stacy "  
            age : "45"
            products ordered id : "1500 - 1600"
           }
           name : "ashley"
           age : "87"
           products ordered id : "1455 - 1660"
          }
           name: " gabrielle"
           age : "67"
           products orderes id : "1568 -1600"

          }
```

I need to return there name of the customers who order is more than > 1500

Comment: `products ordered id` why you have space in the key? Did you try `Array.filter`, you need extract product id from the string?

Comment: sounds like a homework problem. Can you pls provide your attempted code so far,  even if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name products orderes id like that.It should not contain any whitespaces in between.If u want to do so, wrap it with "".

Assuming your product ID is unique , u need to treat the value as integer then only my codes work.

Assuming u already solved the problem above, u can simply do

```
customers = [ { name :" stacy "  ,
            age : "45",
            productsorderedid : 1500 
           },
           {name : "ashley",
           age : "87",
           productsorderedid : 1660
          },
           {name: " gabrielle",
           age : "67",
           productsorderedid : 1600

          }]
          
const filteredcustomers = customers.filter((customer) => customer.productsorderedid > 1500);

console.log(filteredcustomers)
```

Comment: Its a homework problem they gave it to us as strings , with the dashes